# How can I make my navigation bar static?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could make the navigation bar on my website static? Below is my coding for my website.

[Codepen coding](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP)

```
#footer{
  list-style:none inside none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:30px;
  opacity:0.7;
  background-color:#1f1f1f;
  font-size:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share the code for your Navigation bar, you shared the CSS for your footer.

Here is what I think you are going for:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEvxBq

```
#Navagationbar {
   position:fixed !important;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! how would I include the Liam Docherty's portfolio text next to the navigation bar to be included in the static feature within my website? http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRVGXK

I added the background-color just so you didn't get the issue where your name would overlap with other text. I also wrapped your navigation div and the title text into a container div and made that be the fixed element. You should now be able to update the content inside this container and not effect your layout (besides height of that element)